# Icon prolem in the settings

Tags: android

I have a little problem, my appliction always display my icon in the menu, home screen stc. My app is a wallpaper app, but in the wallpaper setting list always display a gray images without my icon. Where I can configure that?

[image: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-nUa_dBdf_SY/Uak1CDI_2CI/AAAAAAAAAJg/ALESKrMV-kY/s1600/screenshot-fblwp.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AndroidManifest.xml find `application` tag and add `android:icon="@drawable/icon"` replacing `icon` with id of your resource.
Something like this:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.cotv.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
    android:theme="@style/QTheme.PageIndicatorDefaults" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I try that, but always show me the gray icon in the settings wallpaper

Comment: And, by the way, may be this will help: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html#sourcecode